# Making derived class use overridden operator

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Base {
public:
    Base operator/(const Base& other){
        Base res;
        cout << "Base /" << endl;
        return res;
    }
    Base& operator/=(const Base& other){
        cout << "Base /=" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived operator/(const Derived& other){
        Derived res;
        cout << "Derived /" << endl;
        return res;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d1, d2;
    Base b1, b2;
    b1 = d1 / d2;
    b2 = d1 /= d2;
}
```

The second assignment outputs `Base /=`. Can I achieve that the second assignment to use the overridden `operator/`, without overriding `operator/=`? I think I have to implement one operator using the other.

This is a homework, so it is OK to give just the basic idea what to do.

Comment: `operator/` and `operator/=`  are different.

Comment: No, you can't. You have to implement /= for the derived class.

Comment: There are no overridden functions in your code (only overloaded functions)

Comment: You could make `operator/=` be a virtual function, and `operator/`  a non-member that invokes it.  I think this is not common practice though (generally you wouldn't use much operator overloading with derived hierarchies)

Comment: @ForceBru, maybe I am missing something, but have I said that they are the same? Actually I have implementation for both in `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

Though being clearly not the preferred way and probably some sort of "ugly", it is possible to use `Derived::operator/` without providing a `Derived::operator/=`. To do that, the following steps are necessary:

1. call operator `/` in the implementation of `Base::operator/=`
2. Make operator `/` virtual such that it is not statically bound in `/=`-implementation
3. Provide an `operator/`-implementation in class `Derived` that overrides the one in the `Base`, i.e. provide an operator `virtual Base operator/(const Base&)` in addition to `Derived operator/(const Derived&)` (note that the latter cannot override since it has a covariant argument type)
4. In this `Derived::operator/(const Base& other)`-implementation, check the dynamic type of `other` and explicitly call the respective implementation.

See the following code:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual Base operator/(const Base& other) const {
        Base res;
        cout << "Base /" << endl;
        return res;
    }
    Base& operator/=(const Base& other){
        cout << "Base /=" << endl;
        *this = *this / other;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual Base operator/(const Base& other) const override {
        cout << "Derived /(Base&)" << endl;
        if(dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&other)==0) {
            // do something specific here, or call base operator:
            return Base::operator/(other);
        }
        else {
            return operator/(dynamic_cast<const Derived&>(other));
        }
    }
    Derived operator/(const Derived& other) const {  // cannot override 
        cout << "Derived /(Derived&)" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d1, d2;
    Base b1, b2;

    b1 = d1 / d2;
    // Output: Derived /(Derived&)

    b2 = d1 /= d2;
    // Output:
    // Base /=
    // Derived /(Base&)
    // Derived /(Derived&)

    return 0;
}
```

Be aware that an expression `Derived d3 = d2 /= d1` is still not possible, because return type `Base &` of operator `Base& Base::operator /=` cannot be converted to `Derived &`.